# Problems with ForeignKey using POST in Django-Tastypie

Tags: django, api, tastypie

I'm building a simple API using django-tastypie.  The idea is I have two resources:

- A **Note** resource representing a note left by a user.  Only the user who created a Note can edit it.
- A **Comment** resource.  Comments can be left on any note by any user.

**TL;DR:** I am unable to limit Note editing to a Note's creator while still allowing any user to comment on a Note.

I am using the following setup for Authentication:

```
class CreatedByEditAuthorization(Authorization):
    def is_authorized(self, request, object=None, **kwargs):
        return True

    def apply_limits(self, request, object_list):
        if request and request.method != 'GET' and hasattr(request, 'user'):
            return object_list.filter(created_by=request.user)
        return object_list
```

In short, a user is only authorized to edit objects for which they are equal to the created_by property (they can only edit the objects they created).

This is linked as follows:

```
class NoteResource(ModelResource):
    comments = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.resources.CommentResource', 'comments', null=True, blank=True)
    created_by = fields.ToOneField('account.api.resources.UserResource', 'created_by')

    def obj_create(self, bundle, request, **kwargs):
        return super(HapResource, self).obj_create(bundle, request, created_by=request.user)

    class Meta:
        queryset = Note.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get', 'put', 'post']
        authorization = CreatedByEditAuthorization()
```

so here, when an object is created, I automatically attach the current user to the `created_by` attribute and link it to the proper Authorization.

A `Comment` resource is simple and just has a `ForeignKey` to a `Note` resource.

**The problem is this:**  if user A creates a Note and user B attempts to comment on that Note, tastypie sends (or simulates) a POST request to edit that Note.  That attempt is rejected as user B did not create the Note, so creating the comment fails.

**The question is this:** Is there a way to either:

1. Prevent tastypie from using a POST to create the reverse-relation to the Note resource *or*
2. Change the Authorization scheme so Notes can only be edited by their creator, but comments can be created generally?

Thanks in advance for any insights.

**Edit:**
I have a big fat hack that can accomplish this.  I'm fairly sure it's safe, but I'm not positive; I'll try constructing some queries to make sure.  Instead of using `fields.ForeignKey` in `Comment` to relate to `Note`, I create a custom field:

```
class SafeForeignKey(fields.ForeignKey):
    def build_related_resource(self, value, request=None, related_obj=None, related_name=None):
        temp = request.method
        if isinstance(value, basestring):
            request.method = 'GET'
        ret = super(SafeForeignKey, self).build_related_resource(value, request, related_obj, related_name)
        request.method = temp
        return ret
```

Each time we try to construct this related resource, we mark the request as a `GET` (since we expect it to be matched to a `SELECT` query rather than an `UPDATE` which matches to `PUT` or `POST`).  This is really ugly and potentially unsafe if used incorrectly, and I'm hoping for a better solution.

**Edit 2:** From reading the tastypie source, as far as I can tell there is no way to filter authorization by the query that will actually get sent.

Comment: Couple of questions - Are you using contrib.comments? Are you using authentication as well as authorization? I have what seems to be a very similar setup (without seem CommentResource) which works fine when posting a new comment on another users object.

Comment: @JamesO No, our comments are somewhat richer than contrib.comments provides (and there is other data associated with a post that is having the same issue).  We are currently just using the built-in Authentication() (i.e. everyone is authenticated).

Comment: Have you posted this as an issue on django-tastypie: https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues ? If it genuinely attempts to update a parent record every time you create something related to it, that's closer to a bug than a feature.

Comment: @JordanReiter see https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1782 - tastypie does appear to save all related fields and there's even a comment that it's doing it 'just in case'.

Comment: @Yoav do we know if save_related is ever a necessary call?

Comment: I'm not sure. You can ask the tastypie developers. However, I don't think your problem lies with the save_related, but rather in the previous call to full_hydrate (where eventually the related Notes resource is being generated, and its apply_limits function called, which limits your results to the current user)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per discussion on https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/issues/480#issuecomment-5561036:

The method that determines if a `Resource` can be updated is `can_update`.  Therefore, to make this work in the "proper" way, you need to create a subclass of `NoteResource`:

```
class SafeNoteResource(NoteResource):
    def can_update(self):
        return False
    class Meta:
        queryset = Note.objects.all()
        allowed_methods = ['get']
        authorization = Authorization()
        # You MUST set this to the same resource_name as NoteResource
        resource_name = 'note'
```

then let `CommentResource` link to notes in the standard way: `note = fields.ForeignKey(SafeNoteResource, 'note')`.

Answer (score 1):

a simple solution should be to check inside the `apply_limits` whether or not the request is for a **Note** resource or a **Comment** resource. e.g. something like

```
def apply_limits(self, request, object_list):
    if request and request.method != 'GET' and hasattr(request, 'user') and getattr(request, 'path','').startswith('/api/v1/note'):
        return object_list.filter(created_by=request.user)
    return object_list
```

Then you're only limiting access to Notes to the same user, when the user is accessing a **Note** resource directly, and not via other related resources, such as **Comments**.

update: or a slightly more secure option would be to check that the request does **not** start with 'api/v1/comment' - so you're just whitelisting the comment access rather than *anything* other than note. The same principle however applies. Be careful with this text-based comparison of the request path, to avoid cases where someone simply appends/prepends string to your url to bypass your authorization. Hopefully prepending is more limited, since it needs to hit the correct url in urls.py, hence why I used `startswith` here. Of course you would have to adjust the path string to match your tastypie urls.

Comment: This seems to be a bigger hack than what I've proposed; table-level permissions should be handled in `Meta` for the correspondent `Resource`.  Additionally, as you say, the text-based comparison can be dangerous (and in fact, would also cause bugs if, say, you were to have a relation to a comment with `full=True` -- in which case the URL might not include /comment/).  In the sense of what is passed back from the bundle, you're right in that the path is really the only relevant data you have.

Comment: not sure how my suggestion is a bigger hack than changing the request method from POST to GET (not to mention the lines of code added). On the solution I proposed, the authorization is handled in the correct place (which is apply_limits), and the url check can be performed whether or not full=True. We're examining the request URL and not any bundle data. My solution can perhaps be improved a little by adding some kind of flag to the request object inside the Comments resource obj_create and then checking it in the Notes apply_limits method.

Comment: It's a bigger hack because it breaks modularity.  Table-level authorization should be implemented at the level of the Resource, not baked into the authentication scheme.  In the above hack, you change the request method, but only when following the relation to a `Note` from a `Comment`, so you keep the scheme change localized to a given Resource.  Before posting the POST-GET hack, I considered using the path (actually in a more robust/consistent way by changing the way paths were constructed) but decided against it because it broke modularity.

Comment: Looks like you're confusing between authentication and authorization. My suggestion was built-into the authorization class of the Notes resource, so I'm not sure why you call it 'authentication scheme' or think it breaks modularity. This is exactly the place tastypie designed to check authorization and limit/allow access. btw, if you're concerned about security, you didn't post the whole code, but seems like the original code you posted might be vulnerable in a couple of places already. Good luck anyway.

Comment: Sorry, authentication should say authorization.  It breaks modularity because you shouldn't be writing a custom Authorization class for each Resource.  You should _choose_ the proper _existing_ Authorization class.  I'm more sympathetic to custom-overriding `apply_limits` at a Resource level, but that still has its share of issues.  In terms of security vulnerability, it is definitely a concern, but it is also a concern with string matching.  In both cases, proper implementation will be secure, but a programmer error down the line will compromise the system.

Comment: I personally think it makes perfect sense to provide custom Authorization classes for your resources. Authorization, if done properly, is likely to be resource-specific anyway. There's no `apply_limits` at the resource level, but you can override `apply_authorization_limits`. As I also mentioned, you don't need to do string matching. You can add a flag to the request. And as far as security - I believe your current code might _already_ be insecure at a couple of places. That's not directly related to your question though.

Comment: This morning I read the source code in quite a bit of detail and I've made a slight modification (see above) -- now I only change to `GET` if I guarantee it is building a related resource via URI.  In other words, I can guarantee that my hack doesn't open any security vulnerabilities.  I found two vulnerabilities in your hack.  First, you can hydrate from a related_resource -- in this case, you can create/modify a `Note` even if your base call was to `comment`.  Second, if you modify the request parameter, but have multiple related resources, it modifies for each, which causes you problems.